# What is the value for Set<Permission> with FacebookLogin in iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-login

I am using the new Swift SDK FacebookLogin for a custom login button and following the guidelines provided by Facebook for Developers (which is already out of date!)

Question: what values do I provide for grantedPermissions (ie, Set), declinedPermissions (ie, Set), and token (ie, AccessToken)?

Thanks

```
    import FacebookCore
    import FacebookLogin

    let facebookLogin = LoginManager()
    facebookLogin.logIn([.publicProfile], viewController: self) { LoginResult in
        switch LoginResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print(error)
        case .cancelled:
            print("User cancelled login.")
        case .success(grantedPermissions: Set<Permission>, declinedPermissions: Set<Permission>, token: AccessToken):
            print("Logged in!")
        }
    }
```

Comment: can clear your question . i can't understand

Comment: My apologies. What values do I provide for grantedPermissions, declinedPermissions, and token?

Comment: do you want get detail ?\

Comment: I would like to know what values/parameters I provide the method.

Comment: see my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass result's declinedPermissions and grantedPermissions .
result which you got with successful login

```
 case .success(grantedPermissions:result?.token.permissions, declinedPermissions: result?.token.declinedPermissions, token: result?.token.tokenString):
```

Comment: It states that "Value of type 'LoginResult' has no member 'token'"

Comment: LoginManager() is your custom class ?

Comment: try this         case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):

Comment: LoginManager() is provided by FacebookLogin

Comment: .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken): generates three warnings all associated stating that the immutable value (from the let) was never used and to consider replacing with '_'

Comment: ok you need to do xcode auto correction....because you have used older version of facebook.

Comment: Thank you, KKRocks. This works (even with the warnings). Not sure what you mean that I have an "older version of facebook"?